# QT Setting Background Image Problem in QT Form?

Tags: qt

I am facing one issue while applying background image to QT form.
The image which i am applying to bg contains some gradient effect but after applying to background its gradient affect is going.

I am using below code at run time for applying bg image :

```
 QPalette palette;
    palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(), QBrush(QImage("bg_all.png")));
    this->setPalette(palette);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QPalette palette;
QString appDir = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(),QBrush(QImage(appDir +"/bg.png")));
this->setPalette(palette);
```

That is fine for me. Please check the file path is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a background to a form, why not set one using a stylesheet instead?

For example:

```
widget->setStylesheet("background-image: url(:/files/bg.png);")
```