# How can I rescale an image and set it to QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, meego

```
QPixmap pic("../image.jpg");

setAutoFillBackground(true);
QPalette palette;
QPixmap scaled=pic.scaled ( 800, 480, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation );

palette.setBrush(QPalette::Window, QBrush(scaled));

//this->setPalette(palette);
QWidget *w= new QWidget(this);
w->setGeometry(0,0,800,480);
w->show();
w->setPalette(palette);
```

But the widget does not show any image.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but what happens if you use QPalette::Background instead?

Comment: Does it work when you don't scale the image?

Comment: it work with main window

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you just trying to show the scaled image in a widget?  I don't think setting the image in the brush and then setting the brush in the palette is the correct approach.

You can just use a QLabel to show an image in a widget.  Like this:

```
QPixmap pic("../image.png");
QPixmap scaled=pic.scaled ( 800, 480, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation );

QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
label->setPixmap(scaled);
```

Comment: but i want show some Qpushbuttons to widget when i used label button not working (becaose label are overlap the buttons) so i am try to show image as backgroung through widget

Comment: if you just want to change the background check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6406940/2174

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the widget before setting the palette. Try setting the palette first.

If that does not help, try specifying the full file path.